# How to disable scrolling of body element?

Tags: jquery

How to disable scrolling of body? `$('body').css('overflow','hidden');` only hides the scrollbars but it does not disable the scrolling. I want to disable the scrolling of the body.

But I want to keep the scrolling of other division intact.

Comment: actually, I just want to disable the scrolling of the body only, but I want the scroll the content inside other <div> inside the body tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this CSS, no jQuery needed for this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

---

[UPDATE after comment]

Try specifying the height of the `body` too:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { overflow: hidden; height: 100% }
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
</style>
```

Comment: that only hides it, but scrolling occurs

Comment: You can always click+drag within the body, regardless of what you do with scrolling.