# How can I avoid scroll up and down when a popup is open in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have this example jquery popup code: http://jsfiddle.net/9jrrd1hL/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Open Dialog Popup</a>
            <p>Table Example:</p>
<style type="text/css">
table.example5 {background-color:GreenYellow;border:1px dotted black;width:100%;}
table.example5 th, table.example5 td {text-align:center;border:0;padding:5px;background-color:transparent;}
table.example5 th {background-color:LimeGreen;color:white;}
table.example5 th:first-child {width:20%;}
</style>
<table class="example5">
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Table header</th><td>Table cell 1
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
      <p>Frames Example:</p>
<iframe src="/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html" width="80%" height="90%">
</iframe>
    <p>Image  Example:</p>
<a href="http://www.quackit.com/travel/new_zealand/milford_sound"><img src="/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg" style="max-width:100%" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" /></a>

    <p>Frames Example:</p>
<iframe src="/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html" width="80%" height="90%">
</iframe>
    <p>Image  Example:</p>
<a href="http://www.quackit.com/travel/new_zealand/milford_sound"><img src="/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg" style="max-width:100%" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" /></a>


    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDialog">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>Welcome to my Popup Dialog!</h2>
        <p>jQuery Mobile is FUN!</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Go Back</a>
      </div>



      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a large background in my real code so, what I want to do is that every time the popup is opened I want it to avoid the user to be able to scroll down or up based on the background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling of body element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789126/how-to-disable-scrolling-of-body-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this on you open popup button

```
<a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" onclick="document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden'">>Open Dialog Popup</a>
```

and your goback button

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back" onclick="document.body.style.overflowY = 'visible'">Go Back</a>
```

You can also add an id to you container div and change the `onclick` function on buttons to `onclick="document.getElementById("containerID").style.overflow = 'hidden'";` and `onclick="document.getElementById("containerID").style.overflow = 'visible'";`

Comment: I think `auto` instead of `visible` is the better choice.

Comment: Do I need to have that code on the go back button? Because I'm using other code that actually closes the popup not just goback to the last page

Comment: How can I pass that to javascript instead of calling that from the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `body` overflow to hidden, like this:

`$(body).css("overflow", "hidden");`

and to get the scroll back just use:

`$(body).css("overflow", "auto");`

Hope it helps.